# Windows always restores old desktop icons

Tags: windows, icons, desktop

I had the problem that windows was mixing up my desktop icons. I installed some tool which was supposed to help but it didn't, so I uninstalled them. I'm not sure but I think I also tried some settings I found somewhere. Now I have exactly the opposite problem. The icons are now stored from something and I don't know what caused this. So I'm looking for some help where I could look to find out what is now keeping the icons restored, because I can't change anything anymore now. When I rearrange the icons, after a reboot they are always back to the same (wrong) order as before.

I already tried to delete desktop.ini and iconcache db as suggested in another answer here, but that doesn't help either.

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: What tool exactly?

Comment: Desktop Restore

Comment: So, Desktop Restore restored your desktop? What a surprise...

Comment: It did not. Something else did, but I don't know what. That's why I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround now, which is ugly, but at least it works, even though I would rather find out where the icons are rememberd, so I can reset them on demand.

I created a temporary folder on the desktop.
Move all icons into that folder.
Reboot.
Move back the icons in the order I want.

After a reboot the new order is now fixed as I rearranged them.